# How to run functions from function-file.html in word add-in

Tags: javascript, office-js

I have a word add-in in which I have added a context menu. This context menu will run a specific function defined in funtion-file.js. The add-in is created with yoman-generator-office.

I have read the official documentation for modifying the xml file to add context menu. I don't know how I can debug the function-file.js. When I click on the context menu It shows in the bottom status bar "... add-in is working on your ..." for 2 seconds and nothing happens. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is modification made in manifest.
To include function file

```
<FunctionFile resid="Contoso.DesktopFunctionFile.Url" />
<bt:Url id="Contoso.DesktopFunctionFile.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/function-file/function-file.html" />
```

To create context menu

```
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="ContextMenu">
            <OfficeMenu id="ContextMenuText">
              <Control xsi:type="Button" id="reDockButtonId">
                <Label resid="Contoso.ContextMenu.Label" />
                <Supertip>
                  <Title resid="Contoso.ContextMenu.Label" />
                  <Description resid="Contoso.ContextMenu.Tooltip" />
                </Supertip>
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" />
                </Icon>
                <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                  <FunctionName>search</FunctionName>    
                </Action> 
              </Control>         
            </OfficeMenu>
          </ExtensionPoint>
```

The function-file.js

```
(function () {
  Office.initialize = function (reason) {};
})();

function search(event) {
    window.open('https://www.google.com/');
    event.completed();
}
```

Comment: window.open() sometimes has issues in outlook web add-in, try using [Dialog APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins). It is possible that your add-in was launched but due to issues with using window.open(), the URL was not opened.

Comment: Please add your html document ?

Answer (score -1):

To debug Add-in commands, you have to use Office Online. For details see [Debug add-in in Office Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-in-office-online).